# Can we create a Validation rule for the account team member to not repeat "Account Coordinator" team role?

Tags: automation, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I am thinking of putting the Validation rule on the account team member object not to repeat "Account Coordinator" team role.

Is it possible to do?

I am looking for a solution "Account Coordinator" team role shouldn't be repeated on account team members of the same related account.

Answer (score 0):

Not a "normal" validation rule because they can look only at the record being modified, not "siblings". (There are exceptions such as vlookup function but won't help much in this case)

See if you can make a roll up summary to account as a count of team members with that role and then make Val rule on account if the count is > 1. It'd waste a field on account but you could achieve that with pure config.

Failing that... You need a flow or a trigger to check existing "siblings" and throw error (don't think flows can throw as such... Silently remove that role? Set a hidden field that would cause a Val rule to fire?). Bit nasty, especially if you start to consider mass insert, mass update, delete, undelete (restore from recycle bin.. if team members can be restored at all, it's possible they're hard deleted)